# Initialize the size of vector else appending wont work, why?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
vector < string > arr(100); // initialise the size of vector always else 
appending wont work,why?
string y;
int x;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>x>>y;
    fflush(stdin);
    if(i<n/2)
    {
       arr[x].append("- "); //appending the first 10 positions with "- "
    }
    else
    {
        arr[x].append(y);
        arr[x].append(" "); //appending the last 10 positions with given 
strings
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    cout<<arr[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

appending isnt working either by using + or append it gives warning please explain why sir?
it gives warning that a pointer to function used in arithmetic operation...

Comment: If the vector is empty, what elements are there to append to?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> initialise the size of vector always else appending wont work,why?

Because this code:

```
arr[x].append("- ");
```

means "call method `append()` on x-th element of vector `arr`". When you create `arr` empty x-th element (no matter what value `x` has) does not exists and your code has UB.